# How to use mongoose to connect to a MongoDB when there is an @ in the password?

Tags: mongoose

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:admin@MongoDB1995@200.100.200.100/database', { useNewUrlParser: true })`

This is the string mongoose uses to parse username and password from targeted database. There is a problem here, the password itself contains '@' and therefore mongoose would parse it incorrectly. So how can I pass a password to mongoose where there is an @ in the password?

I could use `mongodb://200.100.200.100/database?user= admin:admin&pass=admin@MongoDB1995` to connect the database, but once it is connected if I run any command on it it will send out this rejection:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: command insert requires authentication`

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

> mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@host:port/database?options...');

```
var connectionString = 'mongodb://admin:MongoDB1995@200.100.200.100:database_port_here/database';

mongoose.connect(connectionString,{ useNewUrlParser: true });
```

read more [here](https://mindmajix.com/mongodb-port).

Comment: the password is `admin@MongoDB1995` not `MongoDB1995`.

Comment: you need to change your password , remove @ from your password

Comment: I didn't set the password nor do I have the permission to.

Answer (score 0):

From the [connection string documentation of MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#examples)

> If the username or password includes the at sign @, colon :, slash /, or the percent sign % character, [use percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)

You can do percent encoding in JavaScript through `encodeURIComponent`. The below will work whether your Mongo username, password, or database has the above mentioned special characthers and where MONGO_USERNAME, MONGO_PASSWORD, HOST, PORT, and DATABASE are all variables you define some how most likely in environment variables or a config file.

```js
const connectionString = `mongodb://${encodeURIComponent(MONGO_USERNAME)}:${encodeURIComponent(MONGO_PASSWORD)}@${HOST}:${PORT}/${encodeURIComponent(DATABASE)}`;

mongoose.connect(connectionString,{ useNewUrlParser: true });
```

P.S. The `` `string content ${variable} string content` ``, backtick notation, is ES2015 [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and is usable from at least Node.js version 4+
according to [Kangax's compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

For reasons you might want to put your configs in environment variables see [Config the 3rd factor of the 12 Factor App](https://12factor.net/config) guide which mainly states it helps make your app to run in multiple different envionments more easily like development, testing, and production. Also keeping your environment seperate from code helps "with [not] compromising any credentials" should the source be leaked. I highly recommend the whole guide it's got great advice for app portability.